# imagemagick crop creates multipage tif on singlepage tif

Tags: imagemagick, crop, tiff, multipage

I want to crop a singlepage tif file to 2316x2720px:

```
convert 00000001.tif -crop 2316x2720 -repage 00000001_cropped.tif
```

When I use this command the result is a multipage tif file with 4 frames.
First frame with 2316x2720px and 3 Frames with the rest.

How I only get the first frame in the tif file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"frames"*. Can we see the TIF file?

Comment: What is `-repage` without an argument please?

Comment: @Mark: Frame = Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your TIF, I suspect you want this:

```
convert 00000001.tif -crop 2316x2720+0+0 +repage 00000001_cropped.tif
```

Comment: Hi Mark, 
that's exactly what I was looking for.

Why I need "+0+0" ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: That tells `crop` the offset from the top-left corner, and if you don't supply it, it keeps cropping multiple chunks of that size out of the page/image till you have the whole image, which, in your case, means 4 chunks.